# Terminology of Rectangle

Tags: general-topology, analysis, multivariable-calculus, terminology

I saw from the book of topology & multivariable calculus mentioning that

$$Q = [a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times[a_n,b_n]$$

is a rectangle. How to illustrate it? I mean, what does it actually meant by rectangle ?

Comment: Think about $[a_1,b_1]\times[a_2,b_2]$ in $\mathbb R^2$. That's a rectangle. Do you see how the definition is a generalization of that notion?

Comment: If $n=2$, it is {$(x,y)|a_1\le x\le b_1, a_2\le y\le b_2$}, which looks like a rectangle in the $xy-$plane

Comment: Oh, it's the generalization. I thought it is a "rectangle" that I can really illustrate...

Comment: For $n=3$ it is usually called a cuboid or a rectangular solid.